# How can i populate a DropDownList based on BasicDatePicker selection in ASP

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding

I have an asp.net web form application  to bind data (REFERENCE_NO)  to a DropDownList (ddlRef) .ddlRef retrieves data from a MySql database based on the selected date in a BasicDatePickerControl (bdpApps) . My code is as below:

```
    Protected Sub loadRefnumbers()
    Try
        cmd = New MySqlCommand("select idapp,REFERENCE_NO from ONLINELOANS where APPLICATION_DATE ='" & DateFormat.getSaveDate(bdpApps.SelectedDate) & "'", con)
        adp = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        ds.Clear()
        adp.Fill(ds, "DATE_REFS")
        If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            ddlRef.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            ddlRef.DataTextField = "REFERENCE_NO"
            ddlRef.DataValueField = "idapp"
            ddlRef.DataBind()
        Else
            ddlRef.DataSource = Nothing
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

End Sub

I have a getSaveDate function that converts the date format in the basicdatepicker control to the MySql Date format (YYYY-MM-DD). When i debug the app the ddlRef control is not updating to reflect the values from REFERENCE_NO column. Is there anything wrong with my SQL command?

Comment: I am calling the loadRefnumbers()  function on the BasicDatePickerControl's  SelectionChanged method

Comment: I have managed to find a solution for question above.For those who use BasicDatePicker in asp.net webforms the code for my problem is to call the query on the SelectionChanged handler for the datepicker control:

Answer (score 0):

Solution for question above.For those who use BasicDatePicker 1_4_3 in asp.net webforms the code for my problem is to call the query on the SelectionChanged handler for the datepicker control:

```
    Protected Sub bdpApps_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bdpApps.SelectionChanged
    con = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString)
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT id,REFERENCE_NO from ONLINELOANS where APP_DATE='" & DateFormat.getSaveDate(bdpApps.SelectedDate) & "'")
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Connection = con
        con.Open()
        ddlRef.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        ddlRef.DataTextField = "REFERENCE_NO"
        ddlRef.DataValueField = "idapp"
        ddlRef.DataBind()
        ddlRef.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("--SELECT--", "0"))
        ddlRef.SelectedIndex = 0
        con.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```